# Python3: opearations with timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a data file with time stamp as a string:

01/05/2020 0:00

01/05/2020 1:00

01/05/2020 2:00

...

01/05/2020 23:00

Time column is UTC hour. How can I make to convert it to UTC-3, once it is a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use Pandas' [`pandas.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) or Python's [`time.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/time.html#time.strptime) to convert the string representations into [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html) objects. Note you can pass in the appropriate conversion function directly to `read_csv` using the `converter` argument, e.g. `pd.read_csv(..., converters = {"Time": pd.to_datetime})`.
2. Add the desired [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), e.g. `datetime.timedelta(hours=3)`.
3. Store the date as strings again using [`time.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/time.html#time.strftime).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import datetime

offset = datetime.timedelta(hours=3, minutes=0)
df['Time'] = df.Time.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')) - offset
```